# Error in creating a table in mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried some of your suggestions but still the same error.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' (size int(5))' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
            try{
            query = "CREATE TABLE @name (size int(5))";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtboxName.Text;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed space between table name and the column definitions

```
query = "CREATE TABLE "+ txtboxName.Text + " (size int(5))";
                                            |
                                            put space here
```

[sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)... don't use inline parameters. below is sample code with few best practices what I know. But you can't use parameters for table names.

```
public void CreateTable(string tblName)
{
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (size int(5))",tblName), con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code base on your suggestion but the same error. Why is that?

Comment: @user2083771 unfortunately parameters can't use for table names. check my update

Answer (score 0):

i think you intended to use backticks ``  to escape table name but used single quotes instead.

```
  query = "CREATE TABLE `"+ txtboxName.Text + "`(size int(5))";
```

Comment: No, I use single quotes not backticks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add escape sequences to `txtboxName.Text`. There can be some special characters, that break your SQL statement.